# Prove $\{f_n(x)\}$ is not continous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$f_n(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \frac{1}{n} & \quad x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
            0 & \quad x \notin \mathbb{Q}
        \end{array}
    \right.$

Not sure how to show this is a noncontinuous function.

I am supposed to create an example of a noncontinuous sequence of functions that uniformly converges.

I tried using the negation of continuity

Choose $\epsilon = 1/2$

$\forall \delta > 0 |x-c| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(c) | \geq 1/2 \Rightarrow | \frac{1}{n} - f(c)| \geq 1/2$

Comment: Choosing $\varepsilon = 1/2$ won't get you where you want in general. Use the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, and take $\varepsilon = 1/(2n)$.

Comment: Just a thought but I think you can also do this using open/closed sets ie consider the limit points in S=(1/n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image has 2 points, so is not connected, while the reals are.

Or $\frac{\pi}{k} \rightarrow 0$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$, but $f_n(\frac{\pi}{k}) = 0$ for all $k$ while $f_n(0) = \frac{1}{n}$, so $f_n(\frac{\pi}{k})  \nrightarrow f_n(0)$.